# Separate data and text from one cell to provide a duration with a summary

Tags: filtering, date-difference, summarization, delimited-continuations

There.
I am trying to solve a problem with our current data collection at my office. As of now every Friday the entire team use a shared excel sheet to update their assigned project about the next activities with a date and a small description.
For example " 11/17/23 Awaiting proposal approval; 11/10/23 project cost review; 11/03/23 contract proposal due on Monday...........etc." So the project history is in one cell showing as I mentioned.

I am trying to get a monthly data table showing a monthly duration (start and finish) with all notes associate with it for that month (and so on for each month). I have attached a snip how our data looks like and what I would like to accomplish, I am new to excel world and I am not as smart as anyone in this group.
I would really appreciate if you could help, guide, or explain to me how we can accomplish this.
[Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMWr.png)

I have tried to Delimiters by semicolon, but I can't group weekly dates to months and separate texts to group.